Sample Size: Cluster Randomized Trials
I seek a peer check on my approach in calculating the sample size for pair-matched or stratified cluster randomized trials assuming 80% power.
Some background on the study: I am working with infectious disease researchers on designing a cluster-randomized trial to compare a new sterilization method vs. usual care for reducing infectious disease rates in congregate settings (barracks, ships, etc.). This research can significantly impact infectious disease control strategies in these settings.
The unit of randomization is a ship or a platoon, so they will measure the outcome at the individual soldier/sailor level.
Here's the catch: The study will not use simple random samples of units. Instead, it will pair-match the units based on size and other characteristics and randomize one unit of each pair to the intervention. If that's not the best approach, the study will stratify the units by these characteristics and randomize half of the units in each stratum to the intervention.
I welcome your suggestions on my approach in R, which appears below. I base my approach on the methods described by Hayes and Bennett (1999) and adjusted for pair-matching or stratification.
I get the impression that the research group needs to provide me with more details, hence I've made some assumptions for the arguments expected_effect, icc, cv, mean_cluster_size, incidence_control.
This inquiry is cross-posted here.
# Based on Hayes and Bennett (1999)
browseURL("https://academic.oup.com/ije/article-pdf/28/2/319/18477691/280319.pdf")

calculate_sample_size <- function(design = c("pair-matched", 
                                  "stratified"),
                                  n_strata = 1,
                                  alpha = 0.05,
                                  power = 0.80,
                                  expected_effect = 0.1,
                                  icc = 0.01, 
# intraclass correlation coefficient
                                  cv = 0.25, 
# coefficient of variation
                                  mean_cluster_size = 100,
                                  incidence_control = 0.1) { 
# expected incidence rate in the control group
  
  design <- match.arg(design)
  
  # Calculate z-scores
  z_alpha <- qnorm(1 - alpha/2)
  z_beta <- qnorm(power)
  
  if (design == "pair-matched" && cv == 0 && mean_cluster_size == 1) {
    # Non-clustered case for pair-matched design
    sample_size_per_group <- (z_alpha + z_beta)^2 * 
      (incidence_control * (1 - incidence_control) + 
         (incidence_control - expected_effect) * (1 - 
      (incidence_control - expected_effect))) / 
      (expected_effect^2)
    sample_size_per_group <- ceiling(sample_size_per_group)
    total_sample_size <- sample_size_per_group * 2
    total_clusters <- total_sample_size
    clusters_per_arm <- total_clusters / 2
    
    # Calculate the detectable effect size
    detectable_effect <- sqrt((z_alpha + z_beta)^2 * 
                                (incidence_control * (1 - 
    incidence_control) * 2) / 
                                sample_size_per_group)
  } else if (design == "pair-matched") {
    # Clustered case for pair-matched design
    k <- 1 + (z_alpha + z_beta)^2 * (1 + (mean_cluster_size - 1) * 
    icc) * 
      (incidence_control * (1 - incidence_control) + 
         (incidence_control - expected_effect) * (1 - 
    (incidence_control - expected_effect))) / 
      (mean_cluster_size * expected_effect^2)
    k <- ceiling(k / 2) * 2
    total_clusters <- k * 2
    clusters_per_arm <- total_clusters / 2
    total_sample_size <- total_clusters * mean_cluster_size
    sample_size_per_group <- total_sample_size / 2
    
    # Calculate the detectable effect size
    detectable_effect <- sqrt((z_alpha + z_beta)^2 * (1 + 
    (mean_cluster_size - 1) * icc) * 
                                (incidence_control * (1 - 
    incidence_control) * 2) / 
                                (k * mean_cluster_size / 2))
  } else {
    # For stratified design
    k <- 1 + (1 + cv^2) * (z_alpha + z_beta)^2 * 
      (incidence_control * (1 - incidence_control) + 
         (incidence_control - expected_effect) * (1 - 
    (incidence_control - expected_effect))) / 
      (mean_cluster_size * expected_effect^2)
    k <- ceiling(k / 2) * 2
    k <- ceiling(k / n_strata) * n_strata
    total_clusters <- k * 2
    clusters_per_arm <- total_clusters / 2
    total_sample_size <- total_clusters * mean_cluster_size
    sample_size_per_group <- total_sample_size / 2
    
    # Calculate the detectable effect size
    detectable_effect <- sqrt((1 + cv^2) * (z_alpha + z_beta)^2 * 
                                (incidence_control * (1 - 
   incidence_control) * 2) / 
                                (k * mean_cluster_size / 2))
  }
  
  # Prepare results
  results <- list(
    design = design,
    n_strata = if(design == "stratified") n_strata else NULL,
    total_clusters = total_clusters,
    clusters_per_arm = clusters_per_arm,
    total_sample_size = total_sample_size,
    sample_size_per_group = sample_size_per_group,
    detectable_effect = detectable_effect
  )
  
  return(results)
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Mwanza trial example
result_no_clustering <- calculate_sample_size(
  design = "pair-matched",
  alpha = 0.05,
  power = 0.80,
  expected_effect = 0.01,
  cv = 0,  # Set to 0 to ignore clustering
  mean_cluster_size = 1,  
  # Set to 1 as we're calculating total sample size
  incidence_control = 0.02
)

print(result_no_clustering$sample_size_per_group)  # Print sample size per group


Vote to close since, although this is a nice reference and appears to be nicely written code, it is not on-topic to ask us to validate your implementation or source verify the literature. There are 15 mathematical displays and several approaches for continuous and categorical data. All I can say is this is a good start, and perhaps you can verify with some simulations as well as come up with reasonable assumptions about covariance structure other than "set to 0 to ignore clustering" in an obviously dependent data design.

If you write out the underlying math (using Latex), I'd be glad to look at this. This resource on design-based pairwise matching for clustered RCT's might be useful: https://gking.harvard.edu/files/cluster.pdf

@num_39 Thank you! This is a nice reference.
